# Can't execute JQuery function indirectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I imagine the title is very inaccurate, so please do suggest me an appropriate title for this question.

I have an image slider on my webpage which is a plugin called [LightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) and this is how you initalize the slider

```
var lightSlider = $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({ // Code Block 1
    item: 1,
    mode: 'fade',
    keyPress: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false
});
```

LightSlider offers public methods too, one of which is what I'm trying to use. I'm trying to create a custom button to go to previous and next slide. This is the appropriate code for that

```
$('.arrow-left[data-slider="lightSlider"]').on('click', function(){
   lightSlider.goToPrevSlide(); // Code Block 2
});
```

and the corresponding html

```
<div class="arrow-left" data-slider="lightSlider">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> // Code Block 3
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine but I have multiple sliders on the page and assigning all of them a unique id and writing javascript code (Block 2) over and over for each button doesn't seem very efficient to me so I thought of using the `data-` attribute to 'automate' the process. For that I tried

```
$('.arrow-left').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-slider');
    console.log(target);
    target.goToPrevSlide();
});
```

But it didn't work. The error I receive is `target.goToPrevSlide() is not a function`. Well ofcourse it isn't, but I would assume here that `target` would get replaced by it's value `lightSlider`, wouldn't it?

The output of `console.log` is `lightSlider`. My question is why didn't it work and what would be the workaround?

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-slider')` returns a string, not a lightSlider, presumably. Check to see that I'm right, using `typeof(target)`. I also suggest you check out Nico's advice.

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do is this :

```
var lightSlider = $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({ // Code Block 1
    item: 1,
    mode: 'fade',
    keyPress: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false
});
# Assign the `data-slide` attribute of element `#lightSlider` to the instance of `lightSlider`.
$("#lightSlider").data('slide', lightSlider);
```

You will then be able to access your lightSlide directly from your node via jquery.

You might want to take a look at [jquery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) documentation.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of needing to assign each slider a unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this. One would be to initialize each slider in its own context:

```
$('.slider-wrapper').each(function() {
    var lightSlider = $('.slider', this).lightSlider({
        item: 1,
        mode: 'fade',
        keyPress: true,
        pager: false,
        controls: false
    });
    $('.arrow-left', this).on('click', function(){
       lightSlider.goToPrevSlide();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-left">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> // Code Block 3
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, the `lightSlider` variable inside the function block always corresponds to the specific element that's being initialized, even though you've got multiple "slider" elements on the same page.

Comment: I tried that but when lightslider executes it thinks arrow-left and arrow-right  are also slides and it messes up everything. I have to keep the buttons out of lightslider's div

Comment: @VeeK: See my update. If you restructure your HTML a bit, you should be able to group your sliders' elements based on a wrapping div.